# spawn console processes with redirected standard handles in powershell

Tags: powershell, redirect, stdout, stdin, spawning

I have started a process using System.Diagnostics.Process::start() with redirected stdi/o. This process creates another process. I want to redirect the stdi/o of the second process in powershell.

Here is a sample code in which i am running a perl script from cmd.exe process created using System.Diagnostics.Process::start(). I want to see the output of the perl script in the log file as well as send key strokes to the perl interpreter.

Powershell script:

```
$LogFilePath = ((get-location).ToString() + "\Log.txt");
"test stdio redirection of child process" > $LogFilePath;
$cmdProcess       = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process;
$cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName       = "cmd.exe"    
$cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false;       
$cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = $true;
$cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true;
$cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true;    
Register-ObjectEvent $cmdProcess ErrorDataReceived -SourceIdentifier "cmdProcess.ErrorDataReceived" -Action {  if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($EventArgs.Data)) { $EventArgs.Data | Add-Content $global:LogFilePath } } 
Register-ObjectEvent $cmdProcess OutputDataReceived -SourceIdentifier "cmdProcess.OutputDataReceived" -Action { if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($EventArgs.Data)) { $EventArgs.Data | Add-Content $global:LogFilePath } } 
$cmdProcess.start()
Start-Sleep -s 2 ;
$cmdProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
Start-Sleep -s 2 ;
$cmdProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
Start-Sleep -s 2 ;
$cmdProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("D:\batch_files\CC_Automation\test\hello.pl") ;
```

hello.pl:

```
print "Hello\n";
print "press Enter key to exit";
$key = <>;
```

Output:Log.txt

> test stdio redirection of child process Microsoft Windows [Version
>   6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>D:\batch_files\CC_Automation\test\hello.pl

I have found something similar in "C" : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/190351